# When viewing questions sorted by Active, it would be nice to see how a post was modified

Tags: feature-request, questions, last-activity

99% of the time I'm using SO, I am viewing questions of specific tags and I almost always have the questions sorted by "Active". Under the question excerpt is its tags on the left and a status on the right.

The status includes the user (and their rep) that made the latest change, whether it was asked, answered, or modified, and when it was changed.

For example:

> billbybob 35 asked 30 mins ago

> Jimmy 11 answered 5 secs ago

> MaryJane 120 modified 1 day ago

I would find it useful if "modified" could be expanded just a bit to be more specific. At a glance it would be nice to know whether it was the question or an answer that was modified. And it would be nice to know whether it was the editor's own question or answer that they modified.

The following are the four possibilities:

> MaryJane 120 modified question 1 day ago
> MaryJane 120 modified answer 1 day ago
> MaryJane 120 modified own question 1 day ago
> MaryJane 120 modified own answer 1 day ago

This little bit of extra information would allow me to make a more informed decision about whether I want to look into the change or not.

Comment: The fun part is when it shows “modified” but when you look at the question, there’s no edits on questions *or* answers. I’m assuming it’s gotta be on a deleted answer or something, but it’s a little jarring to click on the “modified” and not see anything changed recently

Comment: @fyrepenguin, I believe you are correct in your assumption. And I believe this is because last modification is precalculated and stored, and it doesn't account for permissions level of the viewer.

Comment: In certain cases the modification is a post being reopened which might not be so obvious unless you look at the timeline.

Comment: @fyrepenguin Yes, that frustration goes way down when you reach 10k rep.

Comment: @HangarRash but then you get different source of frustration, namely being able to see the deleted content :P

Comment: @VLAZ I know you added the :P but for me, that's absolutely the best benefit of higher rep. Seriously. It drove me nuts not being able to see stuff that had been deleted.

Comment: @HangarRash but you can see stuff [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60745724) which (for <10k users) has [a picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzmFo.jpg). It's not the worst example out there. Just grabbed what I had at hand. But a lot of the deleted content was deleted for a reason.